# Creating a dictionary with a path name and SHA-256 hash

Tags: python, hash-map

The purpose is just to create a dictionary with a path name, along with the file's SHA-256 hash.

I'm very new to Python, and have a feeling that there's a much better way to implement the following code. It works, I'd just like to clean it up a bit.
    fnamelst = [r'C:\file1.txt',
                r'C:\file2.txt']

```
[fname.replace('\\', '\\\\') for fname in fnamelst]

diction = [{fname: hashlib.sha256(open(fname, 'rb').read()).digest()} for fname in fnamelst]

for iter in range(0,len(fnamelst)):
    dic2 = {fnamelst[iter]: hashlib.sha256(open(fnamelst[iter], 'rb').read()).digest()}
```

Comment: Why are you replacing slashes??

Comment: Well, you've created the dictionary twice. What's the question?

Comment: Note that the `for` loop will overwrite `dic2` each time, instead of extending it.

Answer (score 4):

In your code, you show two ways to create your dictionary, but both are somewhat flawed:

- `diction` will be a list of dictionaries, each holding just one entry
- `dic2` will get overwritten in each iteration of the loop, and will finally hold only one dictionary, again with only one element.

Instead, try this:

```
diction = dict([ (fname, hashlib.sha256(open(fname, 'rb').read()).digest())
                 for fname in fnamelst ])
```

Or shorter, for Python 2.7 or later:

```
diction = { fname: hashlib.sha256(open(fname, 'rb').read()).digest()
                 for fname in fnamelst }
```

The first one uses a list comprehension to create a list of key-value tuples, and then uses the `dict` function to create a single dictionary from that list. The second one does the same, using a dict comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

In python, `for iter in range(0,len(container)):` is pretty much always a bad pattern.

Here, you can rewrite :

```
for f in fnamelst:
    dic2 = {f: hashlib.sha256(open(f, 'rb').read()).digest()}
```

As @tobias_k pointed out, this doesn't do much at the moment as `dict2` gets overriden.
In Python 2.7+ or 3, you can just use the [dict comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) directly.

Answer (score 1):

You have some confusion about using backslahses in Python strings.

`r'C:\file1.txt'` is a raw string and the backslash is a backslash. `r` in front denotes raw.

`'C:\\file1.txt'` is the same string written as a normal string literal. Now the backslash has to be written as `\\`, because otherwise `\f` would be interpreted as a control character `\x0c`.

Doubling the backslash using `replace` serves no purpose here. Moreover, as tobias_k points out, the line with the replace has no effect at all because the resulting modified list is not assigned to a variable.

Comment: Moreover, the line with the `replace` has no effect at all, as the strings in the list are immutable, and the new list is not assigned to a variable.